# Array that does not fit the global size in OepnCl

Tags: arrays, memory, opencl

I can't figure how to deal with arrays which size is smaller that the global size sets in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.

In my atomistic calculation the global size is set by the number of atom. This is the size of the position, velocities and forces. Then, I do a pseudo reduction and store the data in arrays of size corresponding to the number of blocs. I have also a small array to store the parameters of the pair potential.

I don't have any issue with the position, I declare them as `__global const double4 *positions`. My problem is about the two other kind. From my understanding a thread is associated to each array element but that's not what I want for the small arrays. To me the best way to go is to pass the parameter array as `__const` or `__private`, but I'm not sure I can pass an array as `__private` (like I do with scalar) and setting it as `__const` produce the error:

```
:149:80: error: invalid address space for pointee of pointer argument to __kernel function
                         __global float2 *atom_type,__global const double *atmmass, __const double8 *two_body_type,
```

Regarding my reduce array, right now I'm passing it as `__global` the output is just garbage. When I declare it as `__const` I get the same error as above and, anyway I guess that would be an issue the get back the data afterward.

How do you guys would do?

Comment: The error I mention above is solved. My mistake was to use `__const` instead of `__constant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between input or output arrays and the global size that your kernel executes over is not fixed or defined by OpenCL, it is completely up your kernel.

If you want *all* work items to work with larger array and then only have *some* work with smaller array, you can code that. Just check if the global_id is in the range of the smaller array.

If there is some fixed relationship between the array sizes, like 3 to 1, you might instead process there of the large array elements and just one of the small array elements per work item and use one third the global size.

Comment: So, the `global_work_size` value sets in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` is just the number a thread we want to use but we can actually have smaller or larger arrays. Is that right?

Comment: Right. The global size is saying "I need this many work items" and each work item uses global_id(0) to know what to work on. The arrays can be larger or small than the global size. For instance, if you want to read 4 items from one array and then only for the odd numbered work items write their sum to an output array, the input array would be 4 times larger than the global size, and the output array would be half the size of the global size. It is up to what you want your kernel to do.